# How network egress works on google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, network-traffic

I'm having some difficulties understanding the costs of my gcp project, I recently started having network egress costs related to my cloud storage.

I have many processes that consume data from external tables in bigquery , I did not find in the official documentation or in forums if this process has network egress costs related to cloud storage.

I would really like to understand where this cost is coming from...

Comment: Globally: if you stay in the Google Cloud region, there is no egress, in all the other cases, egress applies. The subtilities could be about the network tier (standard or premium).